# How to a reference of a thread, and verification on ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local, thread-local-storage

I'm looking for verification on the following use of [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

I have a service, say `ServiceA` running on a set of processes, say `processSetX` in the system. 
Which `processSetX` will be on `ServiceA` isn't known until runtime and may vary. 
The processes in `processSetX` may run on different threads. 
`ServiceA` has to recognize all processes in `processSetX` the same way.

For this, I'm supposed to write an ID value, say, of type String, to thread local storage (TLS) of a new thread and read this value later on when needed. 
So, the ID of the first thread invoking `ServiceA` will be this ID for `ServiceA` to recognize them all. When this first thread starts another thread, it'll go onto this new thread's TLS and write this ID. From there on, every thread in this chain will pass this ID to the new one.

I'm looking to verify [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) is the way to work this.

I haven't used it before - I want to make sure.

TIA.

//==================

EDIT:

is there a way to get the calling thread's reference?

eg.:

a thread, say `threadX` is making a call to, say `methodA()`. is there a way for `methodA()` to know "who" is calling it? 
if so - `methodA()` is able to invoke a getter method of `threadX` to read a value from its thread-local storage.

TIA

//=================

EDIT-2:

`Thread.currentThread()` returns something like `Thread[main,5,main]`. this may collide across threads.

Comment: `Thread.currentThread()` will get you a reference to the `Thread` **instance** representing the currently executing thread, which is invoking your `methodA`. Note that if by _thread-local storage_, you mean values stored in a `ThreadLocal`, you don't need the current `Thread` instance. This is done behind the scenes for you.

Comment: `Thread#toString()` returns its name, its priority, and its group's name. What do you mean by _collide_? Don't use the `toString` value as a unique identifier for the `Thread`. Use the `Thread` itself (`==`) or its `getId` method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis read EDIT part - read it carefully.

Comment: The second one? `currentThread` returns a reference to the currently executing `Thread`. You've invoked `toString` on the referenced object and printed that out. That's the result you see `Thread[main,5,main]`. Yes, many threads may have the same name, `main`, with the same priority, `5`, and the same group name, `main`. That's why you should not use the `toString` result to identify your `Thread` instances. In that case, there will be no collision. Unless I misunderstand what you are referring to with _collide_, in which case please clarify.

Comment: I don't think you can do that unless the calling thread tells itself.

Comment: If @Roam comes in here, we'll have a trifecta. I'm trying to help you, but I need to understand you. Please don't work against me.

Answer (score 0):

I think at first, you just need a normal member variable.

For example:

```
// Thread
public class CalledThread extends Thread {

    public String myId;

    public void run() {
    ....

// Caller
    CalledThread t = new CalledThread();
    t.myId = "the thread ID";
    t.start();
```

However, you won't be able to access `myId` once you start calling your service classes, so for that you could use a `ThreadLocal`.

In `CalledThread` assign the `myId` to your `ThreadLocal` in `run`.

```
threadLocal.set(myId)
```